# Default Select Option Based on Input Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following `select` on my form

```
<select id="select-1">
    <option value="11">Option 11</option>
    <option value="12">Option 12</option>
    <option value="13">Option 13</option>
</select>
```

And a hidden input

```
<input id="hidden-input-1" value="13">
```

When my page loads, `hidden-input-1` could have a value of either 11, 12, or 13. I'd like to default my select to whatever the value of this input might be. So far I've tried to set this using .val():

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    /*...
         do AJAX stuff to set input value
    ...*/
    $("#select-1").val($("#hidden-input-1").val());
});
```

Which just returns a blank selection. Any ideas on how to nail this?

Comment: _"`/*...
         do AJAX stuff to set input value
    ...*/`"_ Can include ajax `js` at Question ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/osrv7jsa/ Works fine? Maybe Im missing what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: it seems to work fine.....maybe you should add a fiddle to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the elements when they are not loaded into DOM, so you are not getting any value, Below the correct way to do.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-1">
  <option value="11">Option 11</option>
  <option value="12">Option 12</option>
  <option value="13">Option 13</option>
</select>
<input id="hidden-input-1" value="13">
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select-1").val($("#hidden-input-1").val());
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#hidden-input-1").val('12');
var value = $("#hidden-input-1").val();
alert(value);
$("#select-1").val(value);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/98nax561/2/)

Answer (score 1):

`/*...
         do AJAX stuff to set input value
    ...*/`

`$.ajax()` is asynchronous ; `$("#select-1").val($("#hidden-input-1").val());` appear synchronous , could be called before `$.ajax()` completes setting hidden `input` value ? if outside of , following `$.ajax()` success , error callbacks.

Try calling `$("#select-1").val($("#hidden-input-1").val());` at complete handler of ajax call

```
$.ajax().then(function() {
  /*...
     do AJAX stuff to set input value
...*/
  // set `select` value when `input` value set
  $("#select-1").val($("#hidden-input-1").val());

}, function err(jqxhr) {
  console.log(jqxhr.status)
})
```

`